# Run Bash Command from JAVA on AWS EC2 Instance

Tags: java, amazon-web-services, sdk, amazon-ec2

I am new to using AWS SDK on Java. I have created a program to create AWS instances from Java and to check if its running. But I am not able to figure out how to run a bash command on that running instance. Please help!

```
try
                {
                    String lscmd = "ls";
                    Process p=Runtime.getRuntime().exec(lscmd);
                    p.waitFor();
                    BufferedReader reader=new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(p.getInputStream()));
                    String line=reader.readLine();
                    while(line!=null)
                    {
                        System.out.println(line);
                        line=reader.readLine();
                    }
                }
                catch(IOException e1) {
                    e1.printStackTrace();
                }
                catch(InterruptedException e2) {
                    System.out.println("Pblm found2.");
                }
```

But I get an error saying,

```
java.io.IOException: Cannot run program "ls": CreateProcess error=2, The system cannot     find the file specified
at java.lang.ProcessBuilder.start(Unknown Source)
at java.lang.Runtime.exec(Unknown Source)
at java.lang.Runtime.exec(Unknown Source)
at java.lang.Runtime.exec(Unknown Source)
at ListInstances.main(ListInstances.java:79)
```

Caused by: java.io.IOException: CreateProcess error=2, The system cannot find the file specified
    at java.lang.ProcessImpl.create(Native Method)
    at java.lang.ProcessImpl.(Unknown Source)
    at java.lang.ProcessImpl.start(Unknown Source)
    ... 5 more

I am not sure how to connect to the instance I created and run this command on that instance.

Comment: One solution might be to ssh into it and then run the command using jsch?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Could it be that the PATH is not defined and it doesn't know where to find `ls`? Try with the full path (e.g. `/bin/ls`) to verify.